# Безопасная авторизация в PHP

Tags: php, авторизация

Добрый день.
Ищется хороший обзор современных средств авторизации в web, а также готовое opensource решение для безопасной авторизации на сайте, которое легко можно встроить в свой проект. Не хочется изобретать велосипед, нужно проверенное решение. Возможности сервера: PHP 5.3, sqlite PDO. Буду признателен за хорошие ссылки.

Comment: Просветите, пожалуйста, на чем у вас проект собран.

Answer (score 8):

Вас на Google забанили? )))
Вот, например, [готовые классы](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=authorization&x=0&y=0&go_search=1) по вашей теме. Вот [решение с использованием PDO](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5644-PHP-Manage-user-accounts-stored-in-a-database-with-PDO.html), а [тут подробно расписан пример авторизации](http://kotishka.homeip.net/mvc-php/authorization) так же с использованием PDO и SQLite

Comment: Google - штука хорошая, не спорю. Только вот копаться перлах типа:
$u = unserialize(base64_decode($_COOKIE[$this->remCookieName]));
$this->login($u['uname'], $u['password']);
немного напрягает.)